# build cannot find Platform Toolset = 'v141' in VS 2013

Tags: c++, c

error MSB8020: The build tools for v141 (Platform Toolset = 'v141') cannot be found. To build using the v141 build tools, please install v141

Comment: I suggest to upgrade to a newer version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Or select another platform toolset with Project->Properties

Answer (score 1):

The platform toolset v141 is the one released with Visual Studio 2017 (see for example [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7ee90848-dbbb-4d39-acad-0b6d49413569/platform-tools-141-missing?forum=vssetup))

You either have to install a more recent version of Visual Studio, or you can just change the toolset in the project properties (Configuration properties -> General -> Platform toolset, select v120 or older from the dropdown menu)